# iOS How to get size of chart grid?

Tags: ios, swift, charts, swiftcharts

I have used Charts library to make my chart. It really has ton of options, but I have been struggling to implement background for grid. I want to have gradient background, but just for grid part. I have done this by putting my view behind the chart view. I have printed `_viewPortHandler.contentRect`, and from there i positioned my view. Now, while this works, it is not most ideal solution. I would like to somehow at runtime have option to get gridview size, but since `_viewPortHandler` is internal, I see no option to do this:

[image]

Is there any better way to do this?